# Subscribe to eNewsletter

Tags: bdd, specflow

How do I write code in c# for the below Task on
The BDD below- tests to prove that login and register links appear on site
After i used Specflow I have a skeleton code being generated, but then how do I add code? Any Nunit? Story Q, CAN generate code to complete a green test pass?

As a Member
I want to be able to subscribe to eNewsletters 
So that I am regularly informed about developments in the superannuation industry
Acceptance Criteria
Background: I am a Super website Member. Subscribing to enewsletters requires the member to log into Member online section (=MOL)

WHEN I am on the eNewsletters page
THEN text will be displayed to explain how to subscribe to eNewsletters

WHEN I am on the eNewsletters page 
THEN there will be an option to log into MOL and to register for MOL

Comment: As @TimothyHeyden says below - I think you can go a lot further to research this yourself. Take a look into BDD using SpecFlow... there is _plenty_ of tutorials and documentation out there to help you along.

Answer (score 1):

Not trying to be rude, but do you have any experience/knowledge about Specflow/BDD? Because, looking at the question, it seems like you don't. Therefore I think it would benefit you much much more if you would look into that first, before asking someone to write a test for you (what you're basicly doing here). There is enough documentation and examples available from which you can get the answer to this question. Follow a short tutorial on YouTube or something like that to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Specflow allows you to edit an xxx.feature file containing your specification in Given, when and then statements. When you save that file it generates an xxx.feature.cs file just like WinForms generates xxx.designer.cs files.

Should you use "Navigate to" (F12) in VS in the feature file and it will give you the option to copy a template method for you to implement in your own code. These can simply be added to any file in your project that is public and marked with the [Binding] Attribute.

Further details can be found here http://www.specflow.org/specflownew/ProjectSetupGuide.html